# correct way to implement delete feature in grails?

Tags: grails

I have a delete method which looks something like

**Controller Method**

```
def deletemap(Long id){


    try {

        mapService.deleteMap(id)

    }
    catch (ValidationException e) {


        flash.message = "Sorry an error occured when deleting map!!"

        redirect(action: "maps", id: event.id)

        return


    }


    flash.message = "Map was deleted!!"

    redirect(action: "maps", id: event.id)

    return


}
```

The controller method calls service method which looks as follows:

**Service Method**

```
def deleteMap(id){


    def map = Map.get(id)



    if(map == null){

            throw new org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException("Id doesn't exist!!!")
            return
    }



    map.delete(flush: true)

}
```

My goal is to implement this feature as best to completion as possible. I am currently writing some tests and am wondering whether i should handle the case in test when map.delete(flush: true) fails. Can there be a case when this gorm call fails? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to do it:

**Controller**

```
def deletemap(Long id){

    Map mapInstance = Map.get(id)

    if (!mapInstance) {
        flash.message = "Map not found"
    }
    else {
        mapService.deleteMap(mapInstance)
        flash.message = "Map was deleted!!"
    }

    redirect(action: "maps")
}
```

**Service**

```
def deleteMap(Map mapInstance){
    map.delete(flush: true)
}
```

If `Map` has a relation with other domains, it will fail; in this case, you need to validate if a relation exists and delete that one or tell your user that a relation prevents deletion. But that depends in your domain design.

Comment: shouldn't we also handle the case of when the delete fails in the service method. i.e when this code fails map.delete(flush: true) or throws exception. Your solution only handles the case when the delete succeeds. please correct me if i am wrong. thanks!

Comment: You can add a try/catch if the database connection is lost, but I think that if that's the case, your app could be down altogether. My answer cover two frequently cases: Instance not found and instance used in another relation.

Comment: i assume flush is not mandatory. delete() will also fulfill the purpose right?

Comment: Right. Just remember that `If set to true the persistent context will be flushed resulting in the instance being deleted immediately.`

Comment: do you know whether delete(failOnError: true) would be best since the action happens in service class so an exception would cause the transaction to rollback. In case of delete() only i assume the fail happens silently.

Comment: `failOnError` is a parameter from `save` method that throws an exception if validation fails. `delete` don't use that option (http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/delete.html). I don't think `delete` will fail silently.